# Automatically multiprocessing a 'function apply' on a dataframe column

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a simple dataframe with two columns.

```
+---------+-------+ | subject | score |
+---------+-------+ | wow     | 0     |
+---------+-------+ | cool    | 0     |
+---------+-------+ | hey     | 0     |
+---------+-------+ | there   | 0     |
+---------+-------+ | come on | 0     |
+---------+-------+ | welcome | 0     |
+---------+-------+
```

For every record in 'subject' column, I am calling a function and updating the results in column 'score' :

```
df['score'] = df['subject'].apply(find_score)

Here find_score is a function, which processes strings and returns a score :

def find_score (row):
    # Imports the Google Cloud client library
    from google.cloud import language

    # Instantiates a client
    language_client = language.Client()

    import re
    pre_text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', row)
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', pre_text)

    document = language_client.document_from_text(text)

    # Detects the sentiment of the text
    sentiment = document.analyze_sentiment().sentiment

    print("Sentiment score - %f " % sentiment.score) 

    return sentiment.score
```

This works fine as expected but its quite slow as it processes the record one by one.

Is there a way, this can be parallelised ? without manually splitting the dataframe into smaller chunks ? Is there any library which does that automatically ?

Cheers

Comment: Can you show the def of your find_score func?

Comment: Consider using dask

Comment: @Allen I have added the function def to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instantiation of `language.Client` every time you call the `find_score` function is likely a major bottleneck. You don't need to create a new client instance for every use of the function, so try creating it outside the function, before you call it:

```
# Instantiates a client
language_client = language.Client()

def find_score (row):
    # Imports the Google Cloud client library
    from google.cloud import language


    import re
    pre_text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', row)
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', pre_text)

    document = language_client.document_from_text(text)

    # Detects the sentiment of the text
    sentiment = document.analyze_sentiment().sentiment

    print("Sentiment score - %f " % sentiment.score) 

    return sentiment.score

df['score'] = df['subject'].apply(find_score)
```

If you insist, you can use multiprocessing like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# <Define functions and datasets here>
pool = Pool(processes = 8) # or some number of your choice
df['score'] = pool.map(find_score, df['subject'])
pool.terminate()
```